# How do I create a rule to display a system message to users that an event is now over?

Tags: rules

I have an event content type with a date field. Is there a rule I can create that will display a system message to the user that "This event is now over." based on comparing the current date and the date in the date field?

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) can be used for this.  Your message will be displayed using [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7)

Starting at the Admin screen;

1. Click through *Configuration > Rules > Add New Rule*
2. Give it a name and select *Content is viewed* in *React on event*. Click Save.
3. Under *Conditions* click *Add condition*

   1. Select *Data > Data comparison*
   2. Select *node:type* and click Save
   3. Fill in for your content type and save
4. Under *Conditions* click *Add condition* (again)

   1. Select *Entities > Entity has field*
   2. *Data Selector* should have *node*
   3. *Field* should have the field you're wanting to check. This should be a date field
5. Under *Conditions* click *Add condition* (again)

   1. Select *Data > Data comparison*
   2. In *Data Selector* chose your field. Mine was node:field-end-date
   3. Click Continue.
   4. Under *Operator* select *is lower than*
   5. Under *Data value* select *site:current-date*
   6. Click Save
6. Under *Actions* click *Add action*

   1. Select the *System > Show a message on the site* entry.
   2. Enter your *Message*, select the *Message type* (this is the drupal_set_message() status), untick *Repeat message* and click Save
7. Browse to your expired content to see your message.

Comment: This worked well Thanks. Any thought on how to accommodate for a repeating event. One that starts and ends on one day and is repeated every week? Any way to compare the last date?

Comment: Are you meaning that the one node is a repeating event?  i.e. there's not multiple nodes?  I'm not sure. I was fortunate enough to have this sort of situation on the project I'm currently working on.  But each node only has one date.

Comment: correct. one node using date repeats.

Comment: That's getting messy. :/ I imagine you'll need to dig around in some code to get that working. I would start by exploring the options in the date comparison though.

Comment: When I add my date field to the data comparison, I see 4 options even though I only have one date field for the entire site. THis might have something to do with it? I have updated my question above with a screenshot to further clarify what I see.

Comment: I suspect that these 4 values relate to the data collected for the repeating dates.  Looking at the Conditions section again I see that there are "Add or" and "Add and" options.  You'll want to set nested condition based on what those extra fields hold/represent. Sorry I can't offer more advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. What is a "message" to the user, a pop-up window ? a fake field you display above the other fields if the date is passed ?

The easiest thing for you to do without coding a custom module is probably using [Display Suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to create a custom_field in your content type. Use PHP to set the string value of the message if the date has passed as the field body. Or if the date has passed then call `drupal_set_message('Event has already occurred');` Or else return an empty string.

If you want a popup-window you can probably find a suitable module that shows a popup window from this [popup module comparison matrix](http://groups.drupal.org/node/51088).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It would be a system message. I have edited my question accordingly.